# mapper_pre_filter in MRJob

Tags: python, mapreduce, mrjob

I have been trying to tweek the `mapper_pre_filter` example given [here](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/writing-mrjobs.html#filtering-task-input-with-shell-commands). Now, if instead of specifying the command directly in steps, if I'm writing a method to return that command, like this:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.protocol import JSONValueProtocol


class KittiesJob(MRJob):
    OUTPUT_PROTOCOL = JSONValueProtocol

    def filter_input(self):
        return ''' grep 'kitty' '''

    def test_for_kitty(self, _, value):
        yield None, 0  # make sure we have some output
        if 'kitty' in value:
            yield None, 1

    def sum_missing_kitties(self, _, values):
        yield None, sum(values)

    def steps(self):
        return [
            self.mr(mapper_pre_filter=self.filter_input,
                    mapper=self.test_for_kitty,
                    reducer=self.sum_missing_kitties)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KittiesJob().run()
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception: error getting step information: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sverma/work/mrjob/filter_input.py", line 30, in <module>
    KittiesJob().run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 494, in run
    mr_job.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 500, in execute
    self.show_steps()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 677, in show_steps
    print >> self.stdout, json.dumps(self._steps_desc())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 370, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 269, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 348, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 246, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <bound method KittiesJob.filter_input of <__main__.KittiesJob object at 0x10449ac90>> is not JSON serializable
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a late answere. I think you want to change this:
`mapper_pre_filter=self.filter_input,` to
`mapper_pre_filter=self.filter_input(),`.

From the example `mapper_pre_filter` is expected to be a string, not a function. Maybe it'll help somebody in the future.

The stack trace says that the output of the filter is not JSON serializable, because it's probably empty.